# Is there anyway to run different users Simultaneously with in a thread using Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I want to create a single JMX script in which an admin user can log on and create logins for 30 customers then first 10 customers should login using those login details and perform few transactions at the same time  all 30 should be done with in 3 iterations. I want some thing like this

```
ThreadGRoup
->Admin log in request
->Generate user logins->extract the logins from response
-> While controller (count<=3)
  -> user login using extracted logins(10 users logins concurrently)
  -> user perform action 1
  -> user perform action 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated....

My script is doing the following at the moment

```
ThreadGRoup
->Admin log in request
->Generate user logins->extract the logins from response
-> While controller (count<=30)
   -> user login using extracted logins (one user login)
   -> user perform action 1
   -> user perform action 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "CSV Data Set Config" config element. In csv file you could set username as first column and password as second column, then you recover variables in next steps, e.g. ${username} ${password}

Here the official documentation:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Comment: Thanks for the response but, I am already using CSV Data set for admin logins in the thread group

Answer (score 0):

The test modeling does't seem to be correct. I can't think of a scenario, where all the users are waiting for their credentials to be created and when Admin creates their credentials, then, all (#10 users) of them started doing their stuff/actions.

Ideally, these should be two separate scripts where an admin creating some login credentials and there could be some existing users who logs in and do their actions. It's not necessary to be the fresh user. If that's case then you can have a CSV file of existing users doing their set of actions and Admin user are creating credentials for future/new users.

For example,

- Script-1: Create Credentials (Admin)
- Script-2: Login and Do something (User)

BUT, if you somehow convinced with your use case or test modeling, then you can execute the test with 10 threads and add timer with a good amount of wait time in "->Admin log in request" to match the hits/second like you are hitting with 1 thread. Now, use "Synchronizing Timer" in "user login using extracted logins(10 users logins concurrently)" which will make the execution wait for the time when 10 Threads are accumulated then execute it.

[image]